# show hostname in top

Tags: top, hostname

I'm using `top` with `tmux` to monitor the most-CPU-consuming processes on different computers. How can I get the hostname to be displayed in each pane? Can I tell `top` to display the hostname somehow?

[image: screenshot top+tmux]

Comment: Can you get tmux to display the pane titles?

Comment: Possibly, but if so it would likely cost me a full row in each pane, which is quite a lot of 'real estate' (I want to see it for each pane, not only for the active one, so the status-bar is not good enough)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I see it, there is no possibility to do it in `top`. I would suggest using `htop`. If you open the programm press <kbd>F2</kbd> and move with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the column *available meters*. You'll find an entry `hostname` and can place it by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> to left or right side.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like an interesting improvement to top. I will check it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
cp /usr/bin/top /usr/bin/"$HOSTNAME"_top
```

Run the new command you just created, the upper left will show the name of the new command, which includes the hostname.